# MPI - Deal with special case of zero sized subarray for MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY

Tags: multidimensional-array, mpi

I use `MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY` to create a type used to communicate portions of 3D arrays between neighboring processes in a Cartesian topology. Specifically, each process communicates with the two processes on the two sides along each of the three directions.

Referring for simplicity to a one-dimensional grid, there are two parameters `nL` and `nR` that define how many values each process has to receive from the left and send to the right, and how many each has to receive from the right and send to the left.

Unaware (or maybe just forgetful) of the fact that all elements of the `array_of_subsizes` array parameter of `MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY` must be positive, I wrote my code that can't deal with the case `nR = 0` (or `nL = 0`, either can be).

(By the way, I see that `MPI_TYPE_VECTOR` **does** accept zero `count` and `blocklength` arguments and it's sad `MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY` can't.)

How would you suggest to face this problem? Do I really have to convert each call to `MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY` into multiple `MPI_TYPE_VECTOR`s called in a chain?

The following code is minimal but not working (but it works in the larger program and I haven't had time to extract the minimum number of declarations and prints), still it should give a better look into what I'm talking about.

```
INTEGER :: ndims = 3, DBS, ierr, temp, sub3D
INTEGER, DIMENSION(ndims) :: aos, aoss

CALL MPI_TYPE_SIZE(MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, DBS, ierr)

! doesn't work if ANY(aoss == 0)
CALL MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY(ndims, aos, aoss, [0,0,0], MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, sub3D, ierr)

! does work if ANY(aoss == 0)
CALL MPI_TYPE_HVECTOR(aoss(2), aoss(1), DBS*aos(1),            MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, temp,  ierr)
CALL MPI_TYPE_HVECTOR(aoss(3), 1,       DBS*PRODUCT(aos(1:2)), temp,                 sub3D, ierr)
```

At the end it wasn't hard to replace `MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY` with two `MPI_TYPE_HVECTOR`s. Maybe this is the best solution, after all.

In this sense one side question comes naturally for me: why is `MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY` so limited? There are a lot of examples in the MPI standard of stuff which correctly falls back on "do nothing" (when a sender or receiver is `MPI_PROC_NULL`) or "there's nothing in this" (when `aoss` has a zero dimension in my example). Should I post a feature request somewhere?

Comment: Can you please upload a [MCVE] ?

Comment: If it is really needed I'll try to add it as soon as I can (it won't be easy to "purify" the interested chunk of code). Even so, it's maybe worth to underline that I'm not asking for help in understanding an error, but rather in devising a strategy to overcome that strangeness (strange at least in my opinion) in `MPI_TYPE_CREATE_SUBARRAY`, which does not depend upon the source code.

Comment: Why don't you simply define a zero size type, and use it if `nR` or ` nL` is zero, and `MPI_Type_create_subarray` otherwise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MPI 3.1 standard (chapter 4.1 page 95) makes it crystal clear

> For any dimension i, it is erroneous to specify array_of_subsizes[i] < 1 [...].

You are free to send your comment to the appropriate [Mailing List](https://lists.mpi-forum.org/mailman/listinfo/mpi-comments).